# How can I fix this error on Vercel deploy?

Tags: angular, npm, deployment, vercel, portfolio

Hope you're well.
I'm trying to deploy my portfolio on Vercel just to see how it goes and I'm getting the following error:
"Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 127"

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1zzr.png)

So, after I getting this error I can't deploy it.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your angular.json and there will be a fileReplacement config in that json under build block of json. rectify/remove that because the file in with property doesn't exist as per this error. you can read more about file replacements here :-

https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements